# What does it mean if someone says they are "blessed"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, semantics, religion

If Person X says that they're "blessed", does this have to imply that they believe they've received a blessing from some higher power? Or could it just mean they feel "fortunate" or even just happy with their circumstances?

If Person X was an atheist, would it be an "inaccurate" statement if they said they're blessed? Given the current usage of the word, would it be an acceptable way of communicating that they're simply happy with what's happened to them?

EDITS:

This question assumes Person X is communicating via writing, so pronunciation of the word "blessed" isn't a factor. There's also no context supplied by Person X (they don't state their beliefs, and don't divulge further after the one sentence where they say they're blessed). What Person X is blessed about is some kind of project, which has no religious affiliations.

Comment: It means whatever they want it to mean.

Comment: And note that it can be used sarcastically, as in "I've been blessed with a case of shingles."

Comment: I used to be engaged to a very *devout* atheist. He would never have said he was blessed with anything or by anyone, he would have said that he was ***lucky***. But what we infer by someone's words is opinionable. Why would you read so much in a single word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**blessed** in the secular sense [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/blessed) can be sued to communicate happy fortunate and lucky.

> 3. Bringing happiness, pleasure, or contentment; characterized by happiness and good fortune

As in:

> And they [fans] continue to support me in the truck series, so I’m
>   super blessed.
>       Reuters Jul 11, 2018

and

> We don’t get the parents we deserve, and those of us blessed with good
>   ones wouldn’t trade them for any other unearned privilege. Wall Street
>   Journal Jul 19, 2018

and

> His program is backed and blessed by the Chinese government.  New York
>   Times Jul 31, 2018

Comment: @InertialIgnorance no the sentences are!